# Tweepy returns 414 error retrieving status of only most recent tweet

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

My code looks like:

```
user = api.get_user('any_user_you_like')
for status in api.user_timeline(user, count=1, trim_user=1):
    status = str(status.id)
```

When I run this on my own twitter account it returns my latest tweet ID with no issue.  However when I run this on the twitter account of someone with a lot of tweets, like a celebrity I receive the error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 414
```

It looks like something is coming back too large to be parsed, however I'm only asking for 1 tweet and it works on my own user and those of my friends who have roughly 1300 tweets or less.

Any suggestions, or is there a better way to get just the last tweet of a specific user?  The script continues by comparing the tweet ID received to the last tweet by that user to determine if it is new, however there may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.  api.get_user returns a ton of data for the user that isn't necessarily their user ID or anything relevant.  You can forgo the `user = api.get_user('name')`  bit entirely and just do:

```
for status in api.user_timeline(screen_name='any_name_you_like', count=1, trimuser=1):
    status = str(status.id)
```