# Tweepy throwing 'tweepy.error.TweepError' status code 414 when getting an acount's followers

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm learning how to use Tweepy, and building a little app that gets an account's info. However, when requesting the account's followers I keep getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\TwitterParsers.py", line 357, in _get_type_of_resource
    for follower in followers:
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 47, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 195, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 73, in next
    **self.kargs)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Metrics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 233, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 414
```

I get the 'tweepy.cursor.ItemIterator' `followers` using the following function:

```
    def get_followers(user: str, item_limit: int = None):
        if item_limit is not None:
            return Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=user).items(item_limit)
        else:
            return Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=user).items()
```

At first I thought that the error might be due to a bad management of rate limits, but lowering the number of requested items to 1 or 2 makes no difference.

As the HTTP request is built by tweepy, and I am just using the interface, I don't know why I'm getting a 'URI too long' error.

I also have got a 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) once when requesting data from a different account, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

The problem is related to requesting followers, because I am also retrieving the user's account's description, `created_at` date, and tweets (*statuses*), and none of those produce any errors at all.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341988/tweepy-returns-414-error-retrieving-status-of-only-most-recent-tweet) is the only issue I have found that is somehow related to mine, but I do not really know how or whether that could help me.

Thanks in advance. I hopefully am not being too dumb. :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. I was calling `Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=user).items(item_limit)` with a whole `User` object instead of just the `screen_name`.